# Insert a Figure with a caption

Tags: floats, captions

Halo
I want to insert a figure with a caption below with this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\def\pustaka#1{\emph{(\citeauthor{#1},~~\!\citeyear{#1})}}
\def\tpustaka#1{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}



%-------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Test}
\author{name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent
\selectlanguage{british}
\allowhyphens

\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{bagan SEIRD.jpg}
    \caption{Transfer diagram of the spread of Covid-19 and its parameters}\label{seird}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But why, the output was like the picture below? In the caption write **?figurename? 1**. It must be only **Figure 1**, isn't it?
[image]

Comment: `subfig` is a very old, obsolete package that shouldn't be used anymore. Go for `caption` and `subcaption` instead.

Comment: If you run your code, you see that there is an option clash for `babel` because you load it once without a language option and once with the `[british]` option. Remove the line `\usepackage{babel,blindtext}` and your document compiles. (But I also agree with @Miyase's comment about `subfig`).

Comment: @AlanMunn thank you so much, it's work! I'm sorry because I'm still a beginner in latex.

Comment: One other comment, `A4paper` is not a valid option. TeX case sensitive, so the correct option is `a4paper`. You need to pay more attention to the warnings in the log file when you compile. :)

Comment: There is a macro \figurename which is supposed to contain "Figure" in whatever language is being used.  In this case however it contains "?figurename?"  The problem probably comes from babel, although you could fix it by simply by redefining \figurename.